# how to return element on the basis of an property of object which is inside the array

Tags: reactjs

I have an array name task which contain objects. Objects have 3 property id, name and subTask. subTask also an array which contains object which have 2 properties id and name.

Now my question is that how to return element in component return of react.js.

example I want to do like this =>

```
render(){
    return(
        this.state.task.map((e,i)=>{
        
            //return some elements based on task element
            return <some element 1/>
  
            //Also I want to check if an property subTask 
            //of object of task array have some objects or not 
            //if yes then return some elements based on 
            //subTask array element
            if(e.subTask.length!==0){
                e.subTask.map((e2,i2)=>{
                    return <some element 2/>
                })
            }
        })
    )
}
```

In this code if I return <some element 1> then I cannot execute if statement because of return. ButI want to execute if statement also.
How can I achieve this ?

Can someone here help me with this ?

Comment: return should be the last statement in a function. you should place other procedures above return statements

Comment: @marmeladze I know that, but I'm asking for a logic about my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write the following instead:

```
render() {
    return this.state.task.map((e, i) => {
        //return some elements based on task element
        return (
            <>
                <SomeElement />
                {e.subTask.length &&
                    e.subTask.map((e2, i2) => <SomeElement />)}
            </>
        );
    });
},
```

This will render the first element, based on the parent, and if there are sub-tasks it will load those beneath the parent element

Answer (score 1):

If you want to render on some condition, you can use the ES6 syntax for conditional rendering based on condition from mapping your array. Example below

```
return (
     tasks.map((task) => { 
         if (subTask.length != 0) {
             subTask.map(subtask) => return <SomeElement />
            }
        }
      )
```